# Can you prove that my candidate PRP test for Wagstaff numbers (based on Elliptic Curve Primality Proving for Fermat numbers) is a true Primality Test?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, primality-test, fermat-numbers

The test is explained and described in the forum of the GIMPS project:
https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=28658

In short:
$$x_1=W_3=3 \ , \   x_{j+1} = \frac{x_j^4+2x_j^2+1}{4(x_j^3-x_j)}$$

$$\text{If } \ x_{q-1} \  \equiv \ -1/3 \pmod{W_q} \ , \ \text{then } W_q = \frac{2^q+1}{3} \text{ is PRobably Prime} .$$

This candidate PRP test for Wagstaff numbers ($(2^q+1)/3$ with $q$ prime) is inspired by the following primality test for Fermat numbers proved by Denomme-Savin and Tsumura by means of the Elliptic Curves theory:

$$x_1=F_1=5 \ , \   x_{j+1} = \frac{x_j^4+2x_j^2+1}{4(x_j^3-x_j)}$$

$$\text{If } \ x_{2^{n-1}} \equiv -1 \pmod{F_n} \ , \ \text{then } F_n = 2^{2^n}+1 \text{ is prime} .$$

See Posts #1, #4 and #5 for all the details.

See Post #1 for the context.

See Post #4 for the final version of the test.

See Post #5 for the final version of the Pari/gp code.

Comment: I guess this kind of prime numbers has been tested upto a huge limit. Do you really need a certificate for the huge primes ?

Comment: This kind of numbers have been proved prime by means of ECPP already. However, ECPP cannot prove that the biggest known Wagstaff PRPs are prime in a reasonnable amount of time because ECPP is very slow compared to the LLT (or Pépin) for Mersenne and Fermats. Denomme-Savin-Tsumura test for Fermats is only about 5 times slower than LLT/Pépin, and it applies to all Fermats. We need the same (fast and generic) kind of test for Wagstaff numbers.

Comment: Since neither $N-1$ nor $N+1$ can be easily factored , I doubt that there is an efficient test surely giving the correct result.

Comment: Yes, Wagstaff numbers are not smooth. And, with methods based on Lucas-Lehmer Sequences, it is quite easy to build a PRP test simular to the LLT or to the Pépin's test though it is well known that such method cannot be used for building a true primality proof. However, Elliptic Curves are much Richer, I think. WE need EC experts to have a look: only thèse guys can say.

Comment: About a prime certificate, like with ECPP, Denomme-Savin and Tsumura 's method does not provide certificates. So I do not need.